# How can I view parameters and json objects via wcf traces for https rest web service?

Tags: json, wcf, https, trace

Anyone know how I can view how people are using my web service?  I have turned on wcf tracing and can see method calls, but no parameters or json objects. I'm using .net 4 wcf json web service on iis v6 over https.  This would help me greatly in debugging my application any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, figured it out. I enabled message logging, but I didn't add the messagelogging source to a shared listener

Comment: if you answer your own question, you can post it in the answer section and accept it. It lets the world know that this question is done and taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, figured it out. I enabled message logging, but I didn't add the messagelogging source to a shared listener